# UILabel [__NSCFString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

I am having a weird crash related to a UILabel but the crash reporting service I am using doesn't give me much help to locate it. I can't know which Controller and which UILabel is causing it. The only help I have is the following:

```
-[__NSCFString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e0958d0
0    CoreFoundation     __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1    libobjc.A.dylib    objc_exception_throw + 30
2    CoreFoundation     -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 170
3    CoreFoundation     ___forwarding___ + 392
4    CoreFoundation     _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5    UIKit              -[UILabel _legacy_drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 2632
6    UIKit              -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 166
7    UIKit              -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 450
8    UIKit              -[UILabel drawRect:] + 72
9    UIKit              -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 364
10   QuartzCore         -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 112
11   QuartzCore         CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1808
12   QuartzCore         CA::Layer::display_() + 980
13   QuartzCore         CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 202
14   QuartzCore         CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
15   QuartzCore         CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 238
16   QuartzCore         CA::Transaction::commit() + 316
17   QuartzCore         CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 60
18   CoreFoundation     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
19   CoreFoundation     __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
20   CoreFoundation     __CFRunLoopRun + 742
21   CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
22   CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
23   GraphicsServices   GSEventRunModal + 74
24   UIKit              UIApplicationMain + 1120
25   App                main.m line 14
26   App                start + 40
```

Is there anything I can find my way through this? Thanx in advance!

Comment: Try making a break point with exception "all", break "On throw" this will break right before it crashes.

Comment: The problem is that I can't reproduce it in debug mode. This report is from the crash report service in the production application.

Answer (score 3):

Even though it's an old question, for anyone that encounters a similar issue:

If you're using attributedText in your UILabel, check the attribute value types you're setting. For example:

```
NSString* s = @"str";
NSMutableAttributedString* as = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:s];
[as addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:someObjectThatsNotAUIColor range:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];
```

will cause the UILabel [__NSCFString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance crash.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put this in a .h :

```
@interface NSString (extended)
- (void)set;
@end
```

And this in a .m :

```
@implementation NSString (extended)
- (void)set
{
    NSLog(@"[NSString set] ??? impossible !!!");
}
@end
```

Then set a breakpoint on this method.

Answer (score 0):

Search your project for " set]" then you'll probably already find it, as this is a very untypical method name. If that doesn't help, use NSLog to print out all your labels adresses to your console to find out which label is causing this. Like

```
for (UIView *sub in self.subviews)
    if ([sub kindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) NSLog(@"%p", sub);
```

(code untested, correct spelling if necessary)